Squid proxy not caching anything
I can't see any difference between "squid is enabled" and "squid is disabled": the download time for any page seems to be the same. To set up a cache I simply added this line to /etc/squid/conf.d/debian.conf:
cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256
~$ ls -ld /var/spool/squid/
drwxr-xr-x 18 proxy proxy 4096 May 25 15:09 /var/spool/squid/

I restarted Squid and I checked /var/squid/access.log
# tail -f /var/log/squid/access.log
1716643785.019  33921 127.0.0.1 TCP_TUNNEL/200 2737 CONNECT dns.quad9.net:443 - HIER_DIRECT/9.9.9.9 -

1716643833.873 170236 127.0.0.1 TCP_TUNNEL/200 10652 CONNECT firefox-api-proxy.cdn.mozilla.net:443 - HIER_DIRECT/34.149.97.1 -

1716643834.873 171243 127.0.0.1 TCP_TUNNEL/200 4703 CONNECT contile.services.mozilla.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/34.117.188.166 -

1716643834.873 171246 127.0.0.1 TCP_TUNNEL/200 5607 CONNECT spocs.getpocket.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/34.117.188.166 -
....

1716643925.877 172505 127.0.0.1 TCP_TUNNEL/200 23885 CONNECT lemonde2.idalgo-hosting.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/188.114.96.2 -

1716643925.877 174580 127.0.0.1 TCP_TUNNEL/200 824473 CONNECT www.lemonde.fr:443 - HIER_DIRECT/199.232.82.217 -

1716644276.569    207 127.0.0.1 TCP_TUNNEL/200 6671 CONNECT safebrowsing.googleapis.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/216.58.214.74 -

There is no TCP_HIT which would indicate that the cache has been used, but there are plenty of HIER_DIRECT. Since then, in all the many lines I've checked, not one mentions TCP_HIT. I can't figure out what's wrong with my configuration.
less /etc/squid/conf.d/debian.conf

# Squid configuration settings for Debian
# Logs are managed by logrotate on Debian
#logfile_rotate 0

# For extra security Debian packages only allow
# localhost to use the proxy on new installs

http_access allow localhost
#acl localnet src 192.168.1.1/24
#http_access allow localnet
http_access deny all

coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256
logfile_rotate 0

shutdown_lifetime 10 seconds


~# tail /var/log/squid/cache.log
2024/05/25 20:45:58| SendEcho ERROR: sending to ICMPv6 packet to [2620:fe::9]: (101) Network is unreachable
2024/05/25 20:45:59| SendEcho ERROR: sending to ICMPv6 packet to [2a02:26f0:b80:685::432f]: (101) Network is unreachable
2024/05/25 20:46:00| SendEcho ERROR: sending to ICMPv6 packet to [2a00:1450:4007:807::200a]: (101) Network is unreachable
.....

Many errors that I don't understand. Which Network is unreachable? Moreover I don't use IPv6 but IPv4  [---> I added one line to the debian.conf file : dns_v4_first on and errors disappeared]. But still no TCP_HIT.
ps : I tried to comment "http_access deny all" without success.

I may have found the reason:"Squid does not cache anything if TCP_TUNNEL is used for 443. It just relays packets back and forth from client <-> server without knowing what is in them as they are SSL encrypted." https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107963/squid-proxy-wont-cache-anything-tcp-tunnel. Is there anything I can do? It seems hopeless.
